# Every finite dimensional normed linear space has the same dimension as its dual space.

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces

If $N$ is a normed linear space of dimension $n$, then $N^*$ has dimension $n$ as well, where $N^*=L(X,\mathbb{C})$ (all linear functionals from $N$ to $\mathbb{C}$).

Attempt: Let $B = \{e_1,e_2,...e_n\}$ be a basis for $N$. Then define $B' = \{e_1^*,e_2^*,...e_n^*\}\subset N^*$ be a "basis" for $N^*$, where $e_i^*(e_j) = \delta_{ij}$.

Claim:  $B'$ spans $N^*$.

How do I prove the claim? Should I use induction?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write down the coefficients for an arbitrary $f\in N^\ast$ explicitely:
$f=\sum_{i=1}^n f(e_i) e_i^\ast$, since $$f(x)=f(\sum_{i=1}^n x_i e_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n x_i f(e_i)=\sum_{i=1}^n f(e_i) e_i^\ast(x)$$ for all $x\in N$.